# How to install/use RegexKitLite for an iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c, regex, installation

I'm trying to understand how to get my iPhone application working with [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/), I tried searching Google for how to install it but couldn't find anything that explains it clearly. Hopefully this will become a step-by-step guide for anyone searching for it in the future.

Alright so according to the [documentation](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/index.html) it says:

> The two files, RegexKitLite.h and
>   RegexKitLite.m, and linking against
>   the /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib ICU
>   shared library is all that is
>   required.

So I downloaded the .h and .m files, now I am confused about the whole "linking against..." part. Could someone please clarify?

There's a link in the documentation to the ICU from apple's website which contains a make file among others. Do I run this make file? Do I have to be an administrator when I run it? What do I do once/if the files are "made"? How do I "link against" this? Is this done in XCode? Does it need to be done for every project that needs it? Once I've done all that, I assume all I need to do is #import the .h file and start using it, is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add libicucore.A.dylib to your projects Frameworks group. It can be found in:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.1.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
```

Obviously, you'll need to change the version of the iPhoneOS2.1.sdk to reflect the version of the iPhone OS you're building for, and change the iPhoneOS.platform to iPhoneSimulator.platform if you're building in the simulator.

After that you can just add the RegexKitLite source files to your project and start using them.

The "whole linking against..." part is handled by adding the libicucore library to your Frameworks group.

Comment: Nice, it worked, thanks.

I accidentally downloaded ICU-9.11.2.tar.gz (http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/tarballs/other/ICU-8.11.2.tar.gz) and ran the make file, any idea if I need to revert anything?

Comment: I don't get why so many people have to navigate to find the framework they want...  Just open the Info window for the target, go to the first tab, and press the + button for the Frameworks group in the bottom half. It'll bring up a sheet of all the frameworks, dylibs, etc it can find in your include paths.  Select libicucore.dylib and hit "OK"

Comment: What is the difference between libicucore.dylib and libicucore.A.dynlib? Which one should be used?

Comment: Just to note that I couldn't get it to link using just the Other Linker Flags approach (as described in their docs) using Xcode 3.2.5, but the approach of Dave DeLong above solved it immediately. Not tested on device yet, just simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Another way to do this is: go to "Targets" > Your Target, Building Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, click the plus sign, and type in libicucore.A.dylib

Answer (score 10):

You really shouldn't be using the Frameworks groups to add the ICU library to your project, it's not a Framework. Double-click on the project icon in Groups & Files pane in Xcode and go to the Build tab of the Project Info window, go to the Linking sub-section of the tab, double click on the Other Linker Flags field and add -licucore to the flags using the popup window.